# ¿Es posible imprimir 2 cosas al mismo tiempo en Java?

Tags: java, print

¿Es posible imprimir 2 cosas al mismo tiempo con un solo `System.out.prinln();`?

Comment: Para que quieres imprimir al mismo tiempo?? Por favor, pasa mas detalles con un código o implementación tuya.

Comment: Es solo curiosidad, por ejemplo si tengo:
int cont=0;
int cont2=1;
Me gustaria printear los 2 al mismo tiempo con solo un print. O mejor dicho saber si es posible.

Comment: ` System.out.println(cont+" "+cont2);` ??

Comment: Ooh muchas gracias, era mas sencillo de lo que estaba pensando jaja

Comment: Pues eso lo puedes hacer asi: System.out.println(x + " " + y); Con esto imprimes el valor de las 2 variables x y y. E tu ejemplo seria System.out.println(cont + " " + cont2);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para hacer eso tienes que sabes que es concatenación. Simplemente es la unión de 2 cadenas `String`. La ventaja de vaja es que podemos convertir un número o un tipo de dato numérico de manera muy facil, con tan solo poner, por ejemplo, x + "", esta misma se convierte en una cadena.
Entonces, sabiendo esto, tu puedes poner cualquier valor numérico y concatenarlo con `String`, que tambien es valido, porque Java primero convierte el valor de esa variable a un `String` en memoria para poder concatenar. Ojo, no modifica el valor de la variable.

Por lo que, respondiendo a tu pregunta, tenemos lo siguiente:

```
int x = 10;
int y = 20;
System.out.println(x + " " + y);
```

También puedes colocar texto, y sigue funcionando.

```
int x = 10;
int y = 20;
System.out.println("El valor de las variables (X y Y) son: "x + " " + y);
```

O de la siguiente manera:

```
int x = 10;
int y = 20;
System.out.println("El valor de x es " + x + ". El valor de y es: " + y);
```

Tambien puedes agregar saltos de linea mediante el carácter de salto de linea \n

```
System.out.println("El valor de x es " + x + ".\nEl valor de y es: " + y);
```

Lo cual es equivalente a agregar 2 impresiones por `System`, lo cual sería de la siguiente manera

```
System.out.println("El valor de x es " + x);
System.out.println("El valor de y es: " + y);
```